# Cannot instantiate SPI class in Solr version 7.3.1 using JATE2.0?

Tags: java, class, solr, installation, lucene

Im trying to install JATE2.0 plugin on Sorl-7.3.1 but have Errors please help !

When I open the link http://localhost:8983/solr/#/jateCore I get this page:

[image]

This is the error in the loggin

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [jateCore]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$14(CoreContainer.java:671)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:188)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [jateCore]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1053)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:642)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core jateCore: Can't load schema C:\Users\Sonja\jateSolrPluginDemo-master\solr-7.2.1\server\solr\jateCore\conf\schema.xml: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getConfigSet(CoreContainer.java:1081)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1033)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't load schema C:\Users\Sonja\jateSolrPluginDemo-master\solr-7.2.1\server\solr\jateCore\conf\schema.xml: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:582)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:179)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:119)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:92)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:508)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: So what does the logs say?

Comment: So how are you running Solr? Does Solr start without the custom plugin? What is your classpath? Does the solr log show anything about which classes are being made available?

Comment: I just added the exceptions.

Comment: I m starting the server by execute the file start_solr_server.sh  I m on Mac OS. This is the path in the file `#!/bin/sh
solr-7.3.1/bin/solr start -h localhost -p 8983 -d /Users/carbon/Downloads/jateSolrPluginDemo-master/solr-7.3.1/server -s /Users/carbon/Downloads/jateSolrPluginDemo-master/solr-7.3.1/server/solr`

Comment: Which Java version? I also recommend trying a fresh Solr version from solrs own page, and get that running first before doing anything about the JATE plugin.

Comment: here is my file solrconfig.xml

Comment: i m using JDK 8, I following the Demo jateSolrPluginDemo from [https://github.com/ziqizhang/jate]

Comment: The first description there says Solr 7.2.1 is required?

Comment: oh yes  **07 Apr 2018: JATE 2.0 Beta.11 released. The main changes include: 1) migration to Solr 7.2.1.**

Comment: Did you try downgrading?

Comment: Oky now i have installed Solr 7.2.1 with JET2.0 beta.11 but now i also have an error this is what the loggs say: `
ava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [jateCore]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
...`

Comment: That error message has a far larger stacktrace, where the error is located further down.

Comment: I have edited the message of the stacktrace above in the subject of the question.

Comment: As the error message tells you, having a `defaultSearchField` in your schema isn't supported any longer. Remove it.

Comment: it's oky a fix it thx